# How to programmatically log PerformanceCounter

Tags: c#, .net, logging, performancecounter, perfmon

I understand that using `Perfmon.msc` you can create a custom performance counter and by using counter log, you can write the counter value to a text file.

I also understand I can also use this programmatically by creating a performance counter by using [`System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx), and get the counter value using `NextValue()` method. 
Is there a programmatical way to tell the `PerformanceCounter` object to write the log to a text file too (similar to Counter Log in `perfmon.msc`)?

Comment: PerfMon already has the ability to schedule collection of logs to a file in various formats, for an arbitrary set of counters.

Comment: yeah, but i didn't find a way to do that programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using P/Invoke as suggested by another poster gave too much trouble. I suggest running [logman](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788038(WS.10).aspx) from command line using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`

Answer (score 4):

In .NET you will have to sample the counter yourself and write the sampled value to a file. However, the Win32 API has functions to do what you want. For an example of the native API see [Writing Performance Data to a Log File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373228(v=VS.85).aspx). You could try to use p/invoke to call the API.

Comment: @Louis Rhys: Only if you use platform invoke (p/invoke) to call the API from managed code or create a managed C++ wrapper around the API. P/invoke is probably easier, but some API's are really hard to call in that way. I havn't tried the PDH API myself.